# Re-writing perl script to python

Tags: python, perl

I found this perl script from internet and trying to re-write in python, but not able to do it. If anybody who are master in perl and python, please help me. I do hope python can do this more easily than perl.

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Term::ANSIColor;
map(($yo=$_,map(( $y=$yo-$_/3,$l[24-$yo] .= (' ','$')[$y**2-20*$y+($_**2)/3<0]),    (0..30)),),(0..24));
print color('red');
print join("\n", map(reverse($_).$_, @l)), "\n";
```

Output:

```
              $$$$$$$$$        $$$$$$$$$
            $$$$$$$$$$$$$$  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$
          $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
          $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
         $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
         $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
         $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
         $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
          $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
          $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
           $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
            $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
            $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
             $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
              $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
               $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
                 $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
                  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
                    $$$$$$$$$$$$$$
                      $$$$$$$$$$
                        $$$$$$
```

Comment: `"but not able to do it"` - Show your attempt and explain the problems you're encountering with it.  It's very likely that somebody here can help you, but the kind of help we offer here is to answer questions about the code you're writing, not to just write it for you.

Comment: Ya sure, let me try some more and will update my code, for now my print is not near to any sign :)

Comment: This is a very perlish thing to do, see [99 bottles](http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-perl-737.html), random and unrelated, but awesome...not sure if this will be easier in Python.

Comment: Shape "heart", Color "Red", inside "Dollar", You better right in perl, "python"(snake) might scare someone ;) Just kidding

Comment: That's an impressive bit of perl golf there.  Can you do the equivalent of `system("perl heart.pl")` from Python?  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading Hunter McMillen's answer, I converted the OP's perl code to python.

```
l = [''] * 25
for yo in range(25):
    for x in range(31):
        y = yo - x / 3
        l[24 - yo] += (' ', '$')[y**2 - 20*y + (x**2) / 3 < 0]

print('\n'.join(line[::-1] + line for line in l))
```

Other differences between perl/python I noticed while converting the code.

- In perl, you can access undefined variable: `$l .= ...`. But this is not allowed in Python. should be defined beforehand.

  - Accessing over the list boundary cause `IndexError` in python. should be allocated beforehand.
- In perl, `$_` is implicitly  defined. [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) set it for each item it iterate.
- [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) in perl returns the reversed list, while [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) in Python returns an iterator. So I used `[::-1]` instead.
- `1/2` in perl (at least in version 5.14) produces `0.5`. In Python 2.x, it produces `0` (floor division). In Python 3.x, it produces `0.5` (true division); If you run this code using Python 2.x, you will get slightly different result. See http://asciinema.org/a/6681

---

BTW, this prints black heart instead of red one ;)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not nearly as perly as the original. :(

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, i ve been trying more than 2 hours:)

Comment: @simbabque, Do you want something like this one-liner? `print('\n'.join(l[::-1]+l for l in[''.join(' $'[y**2-20*y+(x**2)/3<0]for x in range(31)for y in[yo-x/3])for yo in range(24,-1,-1)]))`

Answer (score 5):

Perl and Python are both dynamic languages and share many similar built-in functions, every function and/or operator used in this Perl code has a direct mapping in Python:

```
Op/Function     Perl     Python
                ---------------
 map            map      map()
 exponentiation **       **
 reverse        reverse  reverse()
 concatenation  .        +
 range          x .. y   range(x, y+1)
```

That should really be all the physical pieces to solve the problem in the same way, you will have to step through each line to actually understand what is going on.

Also you never show where `@l` is defined.

Comment: regarding `@l`, there is a `$l[24-$yo]`, that `$l` is the array.

Comment: @yopy I see where it is used, but I don't see where it is defined. Unlike in Python, in Perl you have to declare variables before you use them using the `my` keyword.

Comment: ah for that, if you don't use `use warnings; use strict;` it won't alert you. So, its not require to pre-defined.